# Python - How to do prediction and testing over multiple files using sklearn

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, scikit-learn, random-forest

I want to train a model and finally predict a truth value using a `random forest model in Python` of the [three column dataset](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B4Ajk8jGD1OxSEl2cnF6TC1lUXM) (click the link to download the full `CSV`-dataset formatted as in the following

```
t_stamp,X,Y
0.000543,0,10
0.000575,0,10
0.041324,1,10
0.041331,2,10
0.041336,3,10
0.04134,4,10
0.041345,5,10
0.04135,6,10
0.041354,7,10
```

I wanted to predict the current value of `Y` (the true value) using the last (for example: 5, 10, 100, 300, 1000, ..etc) data points of `X` using `random forest model` of `sklearn` in `Python`. Meaning taking `[0,0,1,2,3]` of `X` column as an input for the first window - i want to predict the 5th row value of `Y` trained on the previous values of `Y`.

Let's say we have 5 traces of dataset (a1.csv, a2.csv, a3.csv, a4.csv and a5.csv) in the current directory. For  a single trace (dataset) (for example, a1.csv) – I can do the prediction of  a 5 window as the following

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from io import StringIO
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
import math
from math import sqrt

df = pd.read_csv('a1.csv')

for i in range(1,5):
    df['X_t'+str(i)] = df['X'].shift(i)

print(df)

df.dropna(inplace=True)


X=pd.DataFrame({ 'X_%d'%i : df['X'].shift(i) for i in range(5)}).apply(np.nan_to_num, axis=0).values


y = df['Y'].values


reg = RandomForestRegressor(criterion='mse')
reg.fit(X,y)
modelPred = reg.predict(X)
print(modelPred)

print("Number of predictions:",len(modelPred))
modelPred.tofile('predictedValues1.txt',sep="\n",format="%s")

meanSquaredError=mean_squared_error(y, modelPred)
print("Mean Square Error (MSE):", meanSquaredError)
rootMeanSquaredError = sqrt(meanSquaredError)
print("Root-Mean-Square Error (RMSE):", rootMeanSquaredError)
```

I have solved this problem with `random forest`, which yields `df`:

```
    rolling_regression')
          time   X   Y  X_t1  X_t2  X_t3  X_t4
0     0.000543   0  10   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
1     0.000575   0  10   0.0   NaN   NaN   NaN
2     0.041324   1  10   0.0   0.0   NaN   NaN
3     0.041331   2  10   1.0   0.0   0.0   NaN
4     0.041336   3  10   2.0   1.0   0.0   0.0
5     0.041340   4  10   3.0   2.0   1.0   0.0
6     0.041345   5  10   4.0   3.0   2.0   1.0
7     0.041350   6  10   5.0   4.0   3.0   2.0
 .........................................................   
    [2845 rows x 7 columns]
[ 10.  10.  10. ...,  20.  20.  20.]

RMSE: 0.5136564734333562
```

However, now I want to do the prediction over all of the files (a1.csv, a2.csv, a3.csv, a4.csv and a5.csv)by dividing the training into 60% of the datasets whose file name start with `a` and the remaining 40% for testing whose file name start with `a` using `sklearn` in `Python` (meaning 3 traces will be used for training and 2 files for testing)?

PS: All the files have the same structure but they are with different lengths for they are generated with different parameters.

Comment: Do all files have same structure (`t_stamp,X,Y`)? Then just append all the data into a single dataframe and then divide into train and test.

Comment: Yes, all the files have the same structure but they are with different lengths for they are generated with different parameters. Edited my question. thank you.

Comment: @Mahsolid Yes. This is simple.

Answer (score 3):

```
import glob, os    
df = pd.concat(map(pd.read_csv, glob.glob(os.path.join('', "a*.csv"))))
# get your X and Y Df's
x_train,x_test,y_train,y_test=sklearn.cross_validation.train_test_split(X,Y,test_size=0.40)
```

Comment: I am getting this error: `ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [14221, 5689]`. I tried it with a small portion of the dataset i included with my question. I, for example, am trying it with 2845 rows - then make a copy of it like 5 times (in 5 separate csv files: a1.csv, a2.csv, a3.csv, a4.csv and a5.csv)

Comment: What's the sizeof your train and test dataframe ?

Comment: Could you recheck the dataframes given to fit() and predict ()?

Comment: `Size of X_train: 8535,
Size of Y_train: 8535,
Size of X_test: 5690,
Size of Y_test: 5690`. To fit the model, i did `reg.fit(X_train,y_train)`. To predict, `reg.predict(X_test)`. That `ValueError` comes when we do `meanSquaredError=mean_squared_error(y_train, modelPred)`. Should it be `meanSquaredError=mean_squared_error(y_test, modelPred)`? Do we do the prediction on the testing dataset or training?

Comment: use  for test  mean_squared_error(y_test, reg.predict(x_test)) and for train  mean_squared_error(y_train, reg.predict(x_train)) and it can be done on both. However, validation is done on the test.

Comment: I think what you may have done is this reg.fit(X_train,y_train) and modelPred=reg.predict(X_test) and meanSquaredError=mean_squared_error(y_train, modelPred) which is wrong. Mean squared error must be against Y and X of  train or Y and  X of test.Use what I mentioned in the previous comment

Comment: ***Mean squared error must be against Y and predicted Y of train or Y and predicted Y of test.

Comment: I would appreciate if you could have a look at this Linda and thank you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45399525/matplotlib-how-to-plot-both-the-predictor-and-predicted-value-in-the-same-grap

Answer (score 1):

To read in multiple files, you'll need a slight extension. Aggregate data from each csv, then call `pd.concat` to join them:

```
df_list = []
for i in range(1, 6):
    df_list.append(pd.read_csv('a%d.csv' %i))

df = pd.concat(df_list)
```

This will read in all your csvs, and you can carry on as usual. Get `X` and `y`:

```
X = pd.DataFrame({ 'X_%d'%i : df['X'].shift(i) for i in range(5)}).apply(np.nan_to_num, axis=0).values
y = df['Y'].values
```

Use `sklearn.cross_validation.train_test_split` to segment your data:

```
from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=.4)
```

You can also look at `StratifiedKFold`.

Comment: But i want to read all the files whose name start with `a` and then divide the dataset into 60% training and 40% testing buddy

Comment: Any idea on this buddy? thank you so much in advance. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45399525/matplotlib-how-to-plot-both-the-predictor-and-predicted-value-in-the-same-grap?noredirect=1#